# Print subclass name instead of 'Class' when using John Resig's JavaScript Class inheritance implementation

Tags: javascript, inheritance

I' m building a system on top of John Resig' s [class inheritance implementation](http://ejohn.org/blog/simple-javascript-inheritance/) (javascript)

All works well except for the fact that for inspecting/debugging purposes (and perhaps for typechecking later on, I'd like to have a handle on the actual name of the instantiated Class.

e.g: following the example from John, return `Ninja` instead of `Class`.

I'm aware that this name is coming from `this.__proto__.constructor.name` but this prop is readonly. I guess it has to be part of the initialization of the subclasss itself.

Anyone?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you look at the code closely, you'll see a couple of lines like this:

```
Foo.prototype = new ParentClass;//makes subclass
Foo.prototype.constructor = Foo;
```

If you were to omit the second line, than the constructor name will be that of the the parent class. The *name* property might well be read-only, but the `prototype` isn't, nor is the `constructor` property of the prototype. That's how you can set the name of a *"class"*/constructor.

Also note that `__proto__` is not the way to get an object's prototype. Best use this snippet:

```
var protoOf = Object && Object.getPrototypeOf ? Object.getPrototypeOf(obj) : obj.prototype;
//obviously followed by:
console.log(protoOf.constructor.name);
//or:
protoOf.addProtoMethod = function(){};//it's an object, thus protoOf references it
//or if all you're after is the constructor name of an instance:
console.log(someInstance.constructor.name);//will check prototype automatically
```

It's as simple as that, really.